# Accesing local server using Resharp

Tags: android, asp.net-core, android-fragments, xamarin.android, restsharp

I am in progress of implementing a `searchView` but before I do that I would like to successfully reach my local rest api (written using asp.net core). I found a package named [RestSharp](https://restsharp.dev/) which seems to make consuming a rest api very simple. Right now I am stuck at accessing my api from my Xamarin.Android application. I am using a fragment which makes use of google maps, at the `OnCreateView` lifecycle method I am calling a `addData` which is supposed to reach out to my api:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
            //base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.activity_main, container, false);
            // Initialize Views
            _listView = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.searchList);
            _seachView = view.FindViewById<SearchView>(Resource.Id.searchView);
            addData();
            return view;
        }
        public void addData() {
            var client = new RestClient("http://10.0.2.2:44392");
            var request = new RestRequest("/api/Ruta", DataFormat.Json);
            var response = client.Get(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        }
        // More code
}
```

According to [How can I access my local REST api from my android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41196020/how-can-i-access-my-local-rest-api-from-my-android-device), 10.0.2.2:PORT can be used to access my machines localhost:PORT. But this does not seem to trigger a break point inside the rest api's solution (Already tested with Postman).

Comment: run the api with visual studio, and use address localhost:Port breakpoint will be hit.

Comment: Tried this already, breakpoint is being ignored. Could be it related to firing the request in a non async way?

Comment: make sure in visual studio project is run under debug mode

Comment: Started it in debug mode (the breakpoint shown is not related to my api project): https://i.imgur.com/azxhgb5.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing "Enable SSL" on the server's properties under Debug -> Web Server Settings.
And 10.0.0.2 should be used to access a local server from the Android application, for more details for IOS and consuming the api with https check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/connect-to-local-web-services