# RestSharp GET bad request

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, restsharp

I have been dealing with this problem for a few days, currently I have a endpoint which works fine in postman but in my xamarin app it keeps returning bad request even though the resource is fine.

```cs
// Using this URL due to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/connect-to-local-web-services#android
var client = new RestClient("http://10.0.2.2:51811/api/");
var request = new RestRequest("Ruta", Method.GET);   
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

I was wondering if this could be related with the headers? Also breakpoints inside my server solution do not seem to be hit

Already tried:

```cs
var client = new RestClient("http://10.0.2.2:51811/api/");
var request = new RestRequest("Ruta", DataFormat.Json);          
var response = client.Get(request);
```

Comment: And the IP address you are trying to hit is accessible from the network your device/emulator is on? Have you tried it in the browser on the device to see if it responds? Have you tried tool such as fiddler/charles to see what request you are sending?

Comment: Just tried accessing the server from the device's browser, I am still getting a bad request. I'm currently trying this fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724582/error-400-bad-request-when-accessing-web-api-from-xamarin-debug-device

Comment: Well: `new RestRequest("Ruta", DataFormat.Json);` "Ruta" is not json. You probably need to provide something else... What does the request look like in Postman? Can you maybe export and share the Curl request?

Comment: I already tried with `DataFormat.None` and of course! I can share you my Postman request collection: https://www.getpostman.com/collections/75f648e8c46a277a9202
Here's a pick of the request's headers in Postman: https://i.imgur.com/KfCncs2.png

Comment: have you tried https on the address?

Comment: The headers shouldn't really matter. Can you check the log of the API you are hitting as to why it is returning bad request?

Comment: @Stefanija I had http enabled before but it blocked me from firing any requests (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62887536/accesing-local-server-using-resharp?noredirect=1#comment111213597_62887536), I will try configuring later on with: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/connect-to-local-web-services

Comment: Instead of using RestSharp, can you try HttpClient directly? `var client = new HttpClient(); var stuff = await client.GetStringAsync("http://10.0.2.2:51811/api/Ruta");`

Comment: I think I may have fixed it by hosting the server using IIS instead of IIS Express: https://i.imgur.com/V2zdVkj.png, does using this have side effects on the app?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I already tried with the HttpClient by following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/rest

Comment: If you can somehow see the raw request made by Postman and by RestSharp, you'd probably see the difference.